# postgres: aggregate many tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

[image: ER diagram]

Need to `select from projects`  and get something like:

[id] = int

[staff] = agg{users.data, staff.data, role.data}

[chief] = agg{users.data, staff.data, role.data}

[client] = agg{users.data, clients.data, role.data}

[involved] = [agg{users.data, staff.data, role.data}] , [agg{users.data, staff.data, role.data}], ...

[other_project_data]

I know about `array_agg(json_agg)`, but it require only 1 argument. And I get only [staff] = agg{user.data}

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. need sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use json_build_object/jsonb_build_object (key, value):

```
 jsonb_agg(
         jsonb_build_object(
                 'usersdata', users.data,
                 'staffdata', staff.data
          ))
```

## UPD: answer to comment

Using two tables:

```
WITH users AS (
     SELECT 1 as id, 'aaa'::text AS data, 10 as cnt
), staff AS (
     SELECT 1 as user_id, 'bbbb'::text AS data, 5 as cnt
) 
SELECT
     jsonb_agg(
         jsonb_build_object(
                 'usersdata', u.data || s.data,
                 'usersdataarray', ARRAY[ u.data, s.data],
                 'cntdata', u.cnt + s.cnt
          ))
FROM users AS u
JOIN staff AS s ON (s.user_id = u.id)
```

WITH clause emulate your tables.

Comment: Can i aggregate data from 2 tables in one key (column)? 

Like: "'usersdata', users.data + staff.data"

Comment: answer once more. Is effective to do this in db level? Or better to do different kind of formating in backend script languages? 
Which way is faster?

Comment: db. Db exists to manipulate data in easy and fast way :-) If you do some transformation for one record it probably might be the same time as for db as for external languages. But if you do something for many rows - db is better for most cases.